# Git flow question, one feature branch depends on another

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-flow, feature-branch

Git flow question, one feature branch depends on another.
How should i correctly rebase the child feature branch after my parent feature branch merging to master?

The git flow is shown below:
At last I got duplicate commits in my child feature branch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already committed your changes on your feature branch, you can just do:

`git pull origin master --rebase`

From [git-pull Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch. With --rebase, it runs git rebase instead of git merge.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but `rebase --onto ...`[1] seems to be useful:

> First let’s assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a
> feature developed in topic depends on some functionality which is
> found in next.
>
> ```
> o---o---o---o---o  master
>      \
>       o---o---o---o---o  next
>                        \
>                         o---o---o  topic
> ```
>
> We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on
> which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We
> want our tree to look like this:
>
> ```
> o---o---o---o---o  master
>     |            \
>     |             o'--o'--o'  topic
>      \
>       o---o---o---o---o  next
> ```
>
> We can get this using the following command:
>
> `git rebase --onto master next topic`

[1] https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description